# When is inversion natural?

Tags: sentence, conversations, idiomaticity

> A: なんで仕事がそんなにお上手ですか？
>
> Eddie: まあ、そんなことないですよ。まだまだ未熟なので。好きだから、この仕事が

A is a native speaker, and this is part of a conversation that actually took place. A then corrected the last bit and told me この仕事が好きだから would sound more natural. I have been using inversions like this quite a bit when I intend to stress the fact that I *like* or some other verb, but I have never been corrected. Hence my question: when is an inversion like this natural?

Some things to note: 1. 仕事 is actually a placeholder here. In the actual conversation, we were talking about something more private. 2. The thing I said I liked was more than one. More like a list of several things, so it felt heavy enough to me to be moved to the end, foregrounding 好きだから. 3. The thing we talked about was not something that many people claim to like, so I intended to convey my preference more emphatically, but it apparently didn't get across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A: なんで仕事がそんなにお上手ですか？
> Eddie: まあ、そんなことないですよ。まだまだ未熟なので。好きだから、この仕事が。

「好きだから、この仕事が。」 sounds good to me. I think it's quite natural to say it like that in daily conversation. I don't think it should be corrected here.

---

By the way, なんで仕事がそんなにお上手**なん**ですか？ would sound more natural.

Comment: Oh it actually was 「なんで仕事がそんなにお上手なんですか？」 My bad!

Comment: @EddieKal あらまｗw